# ARP behavior in Linux

Tags: linux, arp

I have a L3 switch. Port 1 and port 2 of the switch are added to VLAN 30 and an IP address (30.0.0.1) is assigned to it.

Port1 and port2 are connected to Host1 and Host2 respectively. Host 1 and Host2 are assigned with IP as below

```
L3 swtich port1 (VLAN 30) --- Host 1 (30.0.0.10)

L3 swtich port2 (VLAN 30) --- Host 2 (30.0.0.20)
```

Now I am trying to ping host 2 from host 1. Host 1 is sending ARP request for 30.0.0.20 to the switch, In Linux of the switch for VLAN 30, I can see the ARP request, but I don't see reply or anything, I guess the Linux is just dropping the packet.

My expectation is to ping the Host 2 from Host 1, Is there anything I am missing there.

I am capturing the packets on tcpdump for the interface Vlan30, So I am getting only the tagged packet. 
I don't see any ARP request on Host 2. 
But still I am able to ping 30.0.0.1 from both hosts.

In my HOST 1 & 2, I have ARP learnt for 30.0.0.1 and default gw is 30.0.0.1. 
But when I initiate ping for 30.0.0.20 from Host 1(30.0.0.10), it is initiating ARP for 30.0.0.20.

Comment: Check physical layer, check your vlan tagging.   Is it enabled in the vlan?  Do the hosts align?  Back to basics.

Comment: Can you see the request on Host 2? Are you using `tcpdump` or `wireshark`?

Comment: Is the routing activated on the switch ? See the routing table on each element.

Comment: Can either host ping the switch?

Comment: Can you ping the switch itself (ie: 30.0.0.1) from either or both of the hosts?
Can you inspect the switch's address tables? see if the MAC addresses of the hosts are in it.